# What is tree sort useful for?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tree, binary-search-tree

Tree sort is one of the usual textbook sorting algorithms, where all elements of the list to be sorted are inserted into a binary search tree, and then the tree is traversed to get the elements in order.

Is there any situation where tree sort is preferable over other sorting algorithms that also take O(n log n) time, like quicksort, mergesort, and heapsort?

It doesn't seem very useful since it always takes extra space to store the tree, while those others can be done in-place. And allocating memory for all those tree nodes probably makes it slower too.

Comment: My general intuition for these sorts of questions is that there's no point to most sorting algorithms in the vanilla case, but they may be useful for A: your general understanding of programming, or B: being modified in special cases. Off the top of my head, Tree Sort would be very easy to modify to let you "pause" the sort and add new items during execution, which could be disruptive to other popular functions. (That's just an example of the sort of thing that might come up, mind.)

Comment: To support Edward's comment about pausing: maintaining the tree is useful if you'd like to reuse the tree. Suppose your elements aren't all there yet. Suppose you have to show a sorted list with the elements still arriving. In our async world, this isn't a hypothetical scenario at all. One could argue it's not sorting, but maintaining a sorted data structure that supports quick insertions; but that's just semantics.

Answer (score 0):

**One scenario i could figure out Is in case of external sort**

For Example in case of external Sort If u have List if k list of n
elements total KN elements.

Consider a scenario where u cannot store all of them in memory at once like in case of ram we cannot put every element at once in ram

In that Scenario heap Sort or tree sort is useful
we keep one element from each n list So our heap will be of size K
and we can sort it  by taking out minimum or maximum element from heap

### For more Info -Check External Sort